# Is the net gain of ATP during glycolysis 2 or 8?

Tags: cell-biology, respiration, cellular-respiration

As I understand, 2 ATP are consumed during steps 1 and 3 (glucose -> glucose-6-phosphate and fructose-6-phosphate -> fructose-1,6-bisphosphate) and then 4 ATP are produced during steps 6 and 9 (1,3-BPGA -> 3PGA and PEP -> pyruvate)

So that's 4 ATP produced - 2 ATP used = 2 ATP gained.

However, 2 NADH are produced during step 5 (3GPA -> 1,3 BPGA), and as we know 1 NADH gives 3 ATP so these 2 NADH should yield 6 ATP.

So, if we consider the ATP produced from the NADH, the net gain is 8 ATP. Is this correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Glycolysis - ATP production"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/50598/52196)? Try [searching the questions](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cellular-respiration) tagged with `cellular-respiration`. I'm sure David has already written an answer elsewhere (citing Berg) that addresses this question.

Comment: Have you searched existing questions here?

Comment: @acvill i'm sorry but i dont think that answers my question.

Comment: @BryanKrause yeah i did, couldn't find any answers.

Comment: @Aditya That seems extraordinarily unlikely to me. Maybe you can link to them and explain why the questions/answers you found don't answer your question ?

Comment: @bryankrause after skimming through all the 153 questions tagged with `cellular-respiration`, i've found 3 q&a that are kinda related to my question [this does not talk about the NADH](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/50598/glycolysis-atp-production), [this does not talk about the NADH in glycolysis specifically](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/89245/how-many-molecules-of-atp-are-actually-produced-in-aerobic-respiration)

Comment: and [this does not talk about whether the NADH should be considered during calculating the net produced during glycolysis alone](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/15435/whats-the-point-of-glycolysis-in-fermentation)

Comment: @Aditya That third link seems to cover it pretty well. How do we measure "should" in science? All that's important is to understand what happens. You can make your own "should" arguments however you'd like, as can anyone else - "should" is an opinion.

Comment: @bryankrause don't think my biology teacher likes my opinion of taking the NADH into consideration, just wanted to ask the forum on what would actually be the most "correct" opinion.

Comment: Are those reducing equivalents always converted into ATP?
When they are, is that done as part of the glycolysis pathway?

Comment: Presumably you have a text book. It most likely will have a section on glycolysis in anaerobic organisms, for example in yeast fermentation. This will include consideration of how the NAD+ needed for glycolysis is regenerated in these anaerobic conditions. There is a [SE question related to this topic and my own answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/54186/how-is-nad-used-in-lactic-acid-fermentation-after-it-is-oxidized-from-nadh). This provides an objective answer to your question of "should".

Comment: @david Just saw your answer, it was helpful. I spoke with my bio teacher again, she agreed that 8 could also be the answer along with 2. Thanks for all the help, appreciate it.

Comment: No! 8 can NOT be the answer, whether or not you have beaten down your teacher into submission. Glycolysis is a process that produces pyruvate, 2ATP and 2 NADH from glucose. It ends there. The metabolism of the pyruvate and NADH are separate processes, differing between organisms and between tissues in multicellular organisms.  Even in air-breathing organisms such as ourselves, one can demonstrate this by asking whether erythrocytes perform glycolysis, and then whether they can or do obtain ATP from the NADH. The answer is yes they do perform glyolysis, and no and no for ATP from NADH. Why?

Comment: @david thats because mature erythrocytes don't have mitochondria? so as i understand now, the ATP produced from NADH happens in a separate process independent of glycolysis (the ETS), so shouldn't be accounted for?

Comment: Indeed it does. Your course will, I imagine, deal with the Krebs tricarboxylic acid cycle and the process of oxidative phosphorylation that converts ADP to ATP. If it is a school rather than a university course it may not go into sufficient chemical detail to fully explain the process. But it would be worth waiting until you have finished covering the topic and then raise any questions you have.

Comment: And one last thing (perhaps I really should write an answer). Even changing your question to "What is that potential maximum net yield of ATP from the phosphorylation of ATP and the NADH produced in glycolysis, assuming the latter is oxidized in the mitochondria", the answer 8 is incorrect on two counts related to your statement "1 NADH gives 3 ATP". The minor quibble is that for most NADH generated in the mitochondrion it is now thought 2.5 ATP are generated. The major quibble is that cytoplasmic NADH enters the mitochondrion as FADH2 with an nominal yield of 2 ATP, now regarded as 1.5 ATP.